# How to silently uninstall vSphere Client via SCCM 2012

Tags: command-line, cmd, windows-installer, vsphere, sccm

I am trying to silently uninstall vSphere Client on multiple machines via SCCM. I know my command line is correct. 
    MsiExec.exe /X {GUID}
but whenever I attempt this on the client machine via the command prompt I get an error saying, "This installation package could not be opened. Verify that the package exists and that you can access it, or contact the application vendor to verify that this is valid a valid windows installer package."

I know this might not be the best place to ask this question but I figured I'd give it a shot. Does anyone know what's going on here? Thanks in advance to those who have something to say. Have a good day.

Comment: It could be a number of different issues. If you log into the machine and run that same command does the uninstall work?

Comment: I ran it on the machine and I got the same message. However I believe I was just using the wrong GUID as I no longer have this problem... silly mistake maybe. But would that have caused the error?

Comment: Yes, all installed MSIs live under C:\Windows\Installer. The error you received is displayed if the GUID you're trying to remove can't find a matching MSI under that hidden directory.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: Welcome! Glad you got it figured out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the correct GUID is the answer.....